# How do you get the 'referer' header in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

I want the the url of the page from which a request has been made. How can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The refer(r)er can be found in the `$_SERVER` global variable. Please note that sending the refer(r)er is completely optional and a user-agent can simply decide to not send the refer(r)ing url.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: I have two questions:
1- It is optional, OK, but does it possible changed by the user agent. i.e foobar.com, the user agent could send it as barfoo.net?!
2- Does web crawler's such as Google-Bot, regarded as user agent?

Comment: The referrer can be changed by the browser, by a browser plugin, by some network component (proxy) or by some malware code for example. And yes, most bots identify themselves using the user-agent string.

Answer (score 9):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

The documentations are available here [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Voted for adding link to the documentation.