# How do I get the siteURL calling my page when it is loaded in an iFrame?

Tags: php, iframe, http-referer

Is it as easy as $ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'}? or is there something else that I need to do?

Example:
My Site: sample.php

Calling Site w/iFrame: somesite.com

I want sample.php when it loads to be able to use "somesite.com" for input as a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between an inline frame and a normal page. And loading an inline frame  initially with `src` will send the HTTP referer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your page must not **depend** on the Referer being present nor correct : it is an information that is sent by the browser, and can either :

- be disabled (some firewall/antivirus remove that information, for instance -- or did sometime ago)
- or be altered / faked (if you search a bit, there must be some firefox extension that allow you to fake this pretty easily, for instance)

For more informations, see, for instance :

- [Determining Referer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php)
- [How do you get the ‘referer’ header in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031162/how-do-you-get-the-referer-header-in-php)

These posts both "agree" with me ^^

Now, you can enventually use it to add some feature ; but you must not **rely** on it for your website to work ;-)

Comment: I already know that stuff. I am using the site name + public key + private key for some logging I am doing, I just want to know how to get it when the page is called inside an iFrame. Is it the same way or something else? That is my question, which in your rambling, failed to answer.

Comment: Just for completeness: The Firefox addons are "Tamper Data" and "Modify Headers".

Answer (score 1):

For a truly reliable way to access the parent URL, you can add a GET parameter to the iframe src containing the parent URL when you embed it. You can use Javascript to add this automatically along with the embed.

Here's an example that embeds the iframe at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = '/sample.php?parent=' + window.location;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

You can then access the parent URL reliably from PHP with:

```
$parent_url = $_GET['parent'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As Pascal MARTIN mentioned, you shouldn't trust the Referer value absolutely.

Expanding on Gumbo's answer: since the Referer is transmitted as a header within an HTTP Request retrieving it within a script loaded in an `<iframe>` is exactly the same as retrieving it for any other script.

When the browser requests the page specified by the `src` attribute in the `<iframe>` it will submit an HTTP request like that for any other resource and will include the `Referer` header value.

The value of the `Referer` header will contain the URL of the page hosting the `<iframe>`. So if you had a PHP script named *page-with-iframe.php* and it contained `<iframe src="sample.php" />` the HTTP request for *sample.php* might look something like:

```
GET /sample.php HTTP/1.1
Host: somesite.com
...
Referer: http://somesite.com/page-with-iframe.php
```

In *sample.php* you would use `$ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'}` to retrieve the value and from there you can parse out the hotname *somesite.com*.