# How do i capture URL of a domain that is forwarding

Tags: java, php, url, redirect, forward

I'm not a php coder but I need a script for this situation:

```
xyz.com redirects to abc.com/index.html, then this redirects to abc.com/index.php
```

But the URL in the address bar stays xyz.com  the whole time, so I want a text field of my form in *index.php* to show *xyz.com* as referrer how do I do it through php or java.

And I can't make changes to *xyz.com* as I don't host a site there, it's just forwarding to *abc.com/index.html*

This is the script:

```
<?php 

   $server=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

   echo $server;

?>
```

It keys in  *abc.com/index.html*  in the textfield. How do i get *xyz.com*?

Comment: If the URL in the address bar stays xyz.com the whole time, then you're not really doing a redirect.  Are you actually proxying the request through to abc.com, via mod_rewrite or mod_proxy or something similar (depending on what web server you are using)?  If you are proxying the request, the X-FORWARDED-FOR header might give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Referer HTTP header is usually used for this purpose.  This Stack Overflow question deals with fetching that Header from a PHP file:

[How do you get the 'referer' header in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031162/how-do-you-get-the-referer-header-in-php)

The trick may be making sure that the header is included in the redirect from your html page to your php page.  There is another Stack Overflow discussion about this:

[Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)

In general, if you have control over the index.html page and the server that hosts it, you should be able to find a way to accomplish what you are trying either programatically or via server configuration.

Comment: thanks for your response,  but i got access to xyz.com  so i redirected it directly to  index.php  so this script works

$server=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];