# jQuery ajax referer url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I get the url of the referer in an ajax request?

A file named main.php has jQuery that sends an ajax call to a file named request.php.

Is it possible to somehow figure out the referer when I'm on request.php? To be precise, I want to print the string "main.php" (dynamically) while running request.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the the browser will send the referer page using the header `Referer` as part of the ajax request so you can read it

So you could do something like

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

- [How do you get the 'referer' header in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031162/how-do-you-get-the-referer-header-in-php)

---

If you don't want to depend on the default `Referer` header, pass a custom header of your own

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('my-referer', 'some-value');
});
```

Comment: Can I be sure that the HTTP_REFERER always exists? Or is it safer for me to add the current page to the ajax request itself?

Comment: If you have control over ajax request... you can always set a custom request header

Answer (score 2):

yes on request.php u can get referee like this $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']